# Opening images layer stacked on ArcMap into ERDAS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, erdas-imagine, land-classification

I noticed that ArcMap can open almost anything but if I do a band combination or a supervised or unsupervised classification on ArcMap I cannot open it on ERDAS.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: ArcGIS can export the classified image to an `ERDAS (*.img)` format. Did you try it?

Comment: In what format did you write the raster? GeoTIFF (`.tif`) and Imagine (`.img`) should read fine. ArcInfo Grid and file geodatabase raster are the least likely to be supported by other software.